# Get media image url in views-view-unformatted template

Tags: views, theming, media

I'm using drupal 8, in my template I created a file named **views-view-unformatted--block-12.html.twig** and this is it's content:

```
<div class="row list">
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set body = row.content['#row']._entity.get('body').value|striptags|render
  %}
  {%
    set title = row.content['#row']._entity.get('title').value
  %}
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="promotion-slider-item">
          <p class="mb-0">
            <img alt="Title" data-src="/themes/porto/img/abc/maxresdefault.png" class="lazy-load">
          </p>
          <div class="inner">
            <p class="title mb-1">{{ title }}</p>
            <div class="desc">{{ body|length > 70 ? body|slice(0, 70)|raw ~ '...' : body|raw }}</div>
            <a href="/node/{{row.content['#row']._entity.get('nid').value}}" title="{{row.content['#row']._entity.get('title').value}}" class="btn-read-more"><span class="">Read more</span></a>
          </div> <!-- end .inner -->
        </div> <!-- end .promotion-slider-item -->
    </div> <!-- end .col -->
    {{dump(row.field_images)}}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

I try to **dump(row.field_images)** but null and **dump(file_url(row.content['#row']._entity.get('field_images').value['0']['target_id']))** but url is **/id_sample**. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I did with this code `row.content['#row']._entity.YOUR_FIELD_NAME.entity.fileuri`